# Как нажать на элемент страницы Chromium - Delphi

Tags: javascript, delphi, chromium

Пишу программу Delphi с использованием Chromium. Уже реализовывал нажатие на кнопки и ввод данных в поля. Но на один элемент не удаётся нажать программно никак. У элемента нет id и компонентов button нет. Вот код кнопки:

```
<div class="css-8yenei">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" class="normal css-pw2wcz">
        <path fill="currentColor" d="M3 4h18v3H3z"></path>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 2H9v2h6V2zm4 5H5v14h14V7zm-8.5 2H8v9h2.5V9zm3 0H16v9h-2.5V9z" fill="currentColor"></path>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" class="active css-ixmls4">
        <path fill="currentColor" d="M3 4h18v3H3z"></path>
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M15 2H9v2h6V2zm4 5H5v14h14V7zm-8.5 2H8v9h2.5V9zm3 0H16v9h-2.5V9z" fill="currentColor"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[image: фото элемента]

Это код вызова клика на этот элемент

```
procedure TFormRobot.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var CodeStr:ustring;
begin
    //CodeStr := 'document.getElementById("cancel-order").click();' 
    //CodeStr := 'document.querySelector("css-8yenei").click();' 
    CodeStr := 'document.getElementsByClassName("css-8yenei")[0].click();';
    Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(CodeStr, '', 0);
end;
```

Никак не жимается.